# Category of abelian groups has enough injectives

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

This is Weibel's exercise 2.3.2, posted on MSE before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656345/trying-to-show-that-the-category-of-abelian-groups-has-enough-injectives) but without answer (and not following the hint given in the book)..

For $A$ an abelian group, $I(A)$ is the product of copies of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ indexed by $\text{Hom}_{\mathbf{Ab}}(A, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$.
I know that $I(A)$ is injective, and I wish to show first that there is a canonical map $A \to I(A)$.

Following the hint, a map $f: a\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ for which $f(a) \neq 0$ can be sending $a$ to the coset $[1/n]$ for an integer $n > 1$, and the kernel is $a n \mathbb{Z}$.
I can still construct a map $a \mathbb{Z} \to I(A)$ given by $a \mapsto f(a) \times f(a) \times \dots$, and so there is also a map $A \to I(A)$ lifting this map.
However the map $a \mathbb{Z} \to I(A)$ has nonzero kernel, so it is not clear that the lifted map is an injection.

On the other hand, I could also send $a \in a\mathbb{Z}$ to $f_1(a) \times f_2(a) \times \dots$ where the $f_i \in \text{Hom}_{\mathbf{Ab}}(A, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ index $I(A)$. But again, since $f_i$ sends $a$ to some coset $[1/n_i]$, the kernel is $an_i\mathbb{Z}$, so the kernel of this map would look like $a n_1 \mathbb{Z} \times an_2 \mathbb{Z} \times \dots$, which also isn't correct - this is where I am stuck, I am not sure what else can be tried.

Comment: The kernel is the intersection of those groups in the second case. The idea in the second case is correct, and all you need to do to prove the map is injective is find a map from $A$ to $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ that doesn't vanish on $a$ for any $a\in A$.

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out how to find the map which doesn't vanish on any $a$ - surely $na$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ will be sent to the zero coset in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If I can find a map $A \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ which doesn't vanish on $A$, then won't I just have an injection $A \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, proving that there are enough injectives? This doesn't seem to follow Weibel's hint.

Comment: The hint is used in the following way, define the map on $a\Bbb{Z}$ as suggested, then extend to all of $A$ using injectivity of $\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Oh sorry to be clear, you want a lot of maps, not one map. I.e. $\forall a\exists\phi_a$, not $\exists\phi\forall a$.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the second part. I've written an attempted answer to this question - could you please take a look and offer some critique? I think it implements what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Attempted solution which I think is correct:**

The map $\coprod_{a \in A} a\mathbb{Z} \to A$ is an injection, and I can define also a map $\phi: \coprod_{a \in A} a\mathbb{Z} \to I(A)$ by sending $a$ to $f_1(a) \times f_2 (a) \times \dots$, where the $f_i$ run over all elements in $\text{Hom}(A, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ as I wrote in my question (this map is actually canonical too).
Since we found a map $f: a\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ for which $f(a) \neq 0$, then the kernel of $\phi$ is zero, and so the lifted map $A \to I(A)$ is also an injection.

I think this is correct, but I am not 100% sure, so I won't accept this as an answer until I can confirm its correctness.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be overly complicating this part of the book.
What Weibel meant was the following.

Our objective is to prove that $\mathbf{Ab}$ has enough injectives.
Let $A$ be an abelian group.
To do this, we set $I(A) = (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})^{\mathrm{Hom}(A, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})}$.
As $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is divisible, by **Corollary 2.3.2**, it is injective.
Thus, $I(A)$ is injective because it is a product of injectives.
This is the part where you get confused because Weibel is not so explicit, I think.
We have a canonical homomorphism
\begin{align*}
  e_A: A &\to I(A), \\
  e_A(a) &= (f(a))_{f \in \mathrm{Hom}(A, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})}.
\end{align*}
To prove $A$ is injective, it is enough to prove that $e_A$ is injective.
This is the content of **Exercise 2.3.2**.
Let $a \in A, a \neq 0$.
Our objective is to find a homomorphism $f: A \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(a) \neq 0$.
We have two cases, depending on whether the order of $a$ is finite or not:

1. $|a| = \infty$.
   In this case, we can map $a$ to any nonzero element of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, say $1/2$, obtaining a homomorphism $f': a\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f'(a) \neq 0$.
2. $|a| = m$ for some integer $m > 1$.
   In this case, we define $f'(a) = 1/m \neq 0$.
   By the definition of the order of $a$, this is well-defined.

In any case, by **Baer's Criterion 2.3.1**, we can extend $f'$ to a homomorphism $f: A \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(a) \neq 0$.
By the definition of $e_A$, this implies that $e_A(a) \neq 0$.
Thus, $e_A$ is injective.